# ElasticNetCVの引数n_alphasについて

Tags: python, 機械学習, scikit-learn

scikit-learn公式ドキュメントには「Number of alphas along the regularization path, used for each l1_ratio.」とありますが、Elasticnetの「n_alpha」という引数はどのようなものかご教授いただけますでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

通常のElasticNetの場合は交差検証を内部的に行わないので単一のalphaを指定しますが、CVがつく場合は交差検証でパラメータをグリッドサーチするように処理するので、alphaを複数指定(alphas)できます。n_alphasを指定してalphas=Noneとすると、alphasはn_alphasの数だけ自動設定されます。ElasticNetCVはこのalphasそれぞれで訓練されたモデルでスコアを出し、bestとなるalphaを見つけ出します。